# Why doesnt code inside ContentPlaceHolder cause an exception?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

AFAIK anything placed inside `ContentPlaceHolder` is simply overwritten when the child merges with the Master.  This can make for some interesting troubleshooting.  I had a situation where all my javascript would simply not work.  After a while I noticed somebody had placed all the header information for the .Master inside the `ContentPlaceHolder` for the header.

So this leaves me to wonder...Why doesn't ASP.NET toss an exception when content is found inside the placeholder?  Is there some way to place content inside here legally?  Why would you ever want to do that?  Or, is this a technical limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a way to supply a default template if no child overrides the content placeholder.  If the child page doesn't implement that content section, then the default appears in its place.

HTH.

Comment: +1 If this is the reasoning behind it, MS should have made a `<DefaultContent>` tag to distinguish between a coding error and real content.  Its too easy an error to miss and hard to track down.